# connect four loop to be able to play again caused indentation errors in the main function

Tags: python

I can't figure out how to indent it properly to work. I had it before I added the loop and playAgain variable, and tabbing was doing weird things. I fixed some of it, but it never makes a move, it just always repeats asking for a move.

```
#myBoard is a 2d array storing the board. col is the column a player is                                                                                                                                     
#trying to move, and player is the player to move. If it is a valid move,                                                                                                                                   
#the program will go ahead and change myBoard.                                                                                                                                                              
def move2(myBoard, col, player):
     if player == True:
         for i in range(len(myBoard) - 1,-1,-1):
             if myBoard[i][col] == 0:
                 myBoard[i][col] = 1
                 player = False
                 lastRow = i
                 break
     else:
         for i in range(len(myBoard) - 1,-1,-1):
            if myBoard[i][col] == 0:
                myBoard[i][col] = -1
                player = True
                lastRow = i
                break
     return myBoard, player, lastRow

#could't get this to work in time                                                                                                                                                                           
#                                                                                                                                                                                                           
#Saves the game to a text file                                                                                                                                                                              
#def save(filename, myBoard, player):                                                                                                                                                                       
#     fileThing = open(filename 'w')                                                                                                                                                                        
#     for i in range(0, len(myBoard)):                                                                                                                                                                      
#          for j in range(0, len(i)):                                                                                                                                                                       
#               fileThing.write(j)                                                                                                                                                                          
#          fileThing.write("\n")                                                                                                                                                                            
#     fileThing.write(turn)                                                                                                                                                                                 
#     fileThing.close()                                                                                                                                                                                     

#Returns 1 if player 1 has won, a -1 if player 2 has won, and 0 otherwise.                                                                                                                                  
#lastColPlayed is the last valid move that was made.                                                                                                                                                        
def checkWin(myBoard, lastColPlayed, lastRow):
    player1amount = 0
    player2amount = 0
    winDiagnol = 0
    winDiagnol2 = 0
    for i in range(len(myBoard)):
         if myBoard[i][lastColPlayed] == 1:
              player2amount = 0
              player1amount += 1
         if myBoard[i][lastColPlayed] == -1:
              playet1amount = 0
              player2amount += 1
    try:
         if myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == myBoard[lastRow - 1][lastColPlayed - 1] and myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == myBoard[lastRow - 2][lastColPlayed - 2] and myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] =\
= myBoard[lastRow - 3][lastColPlayed - 3]:
              if myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == 1:
                   winDiagnol = 1
              elif myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == -1:
                   winDiagnol = -1
    except IndexError:
         pass
    try:
         if myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == myBoard[lastRow + 1][lastColPlayed - 1] and myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == myBoard[lastRow + 2][lastColPlayed - 2] and myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] =\
= myBoard[lastRow + 3][lastColPlayed - 3]:
              if myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == 1:
                   winDiagnol2 = 1
              elif myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == -1:
                   winDiagnol2 = -1
    except IndexError:
         pass
    if player1amount > 3 or winDiagnol == 1 or winDiagnol2 == 1:
         return 1
    elif player2amount > 3 or winDiagnol == -1 or winDiagnol2 == -1:
         return -1
    else:
         return 0

#prints myBoard to the screen                                                                                                                                                                               
def printBoard(myBoard):
    for row in myBoard:
        for item in row:
            if item == 0:
                print("_", end="")
            elif item == -1:
                print("0", end="")
           elif item == 1:
                print("X", end="")
        print()

#returns true if it's a draw                                                                                                                                                                                
def isDraw(myBoard, won):
     Full = True
     for row in myBoard:
          for item in row:
               if item == 0:
                    Full = False
     if Full == True and won != 1 and won != -1:
          return True
     else:
          return False


def main():
     lastRow = 0
     won = 0
     draw = False
     player1turn = True
     print("Welcome to Connect Four!")
     playAgain = True
     while playAgain != "n":
          rows = input("Please enter a number of rows: ")
          check = True
          while check == True:
               try:
                    if int(rows) <= 4:
                         while int(rows) <= 4:
                              rows = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
                    else:
                         check = False
               except ValueError:
                    rows = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
          columns = input("Please enter a number of columns: ")
          check2 = True
          while check2 == True:
               try:
                    if int(columns) <= 4:
                         while int(columns) <= 4:
                              columns = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
                    else:
                         check2 = False
               except ValueError:
                    columns = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
          myBoard = []
          myBoardTemp = []
          for i in range(int(columns)):
               myBoardTemp.append(0)
          for i in range(int(rows)):
               myBoard.append([0] * int(columns))
         printBoard(myBoard)
          check3 = True
          while won == 0 and draw == False:
               move = input("Please enter a move: ")
               while check3 == True:
                    try:
                         if int(move) < 0 or int(move) > len(myBoard[0]):
                              while int(move) < 0 or int(move) > len(myBoard[0]):
                                   move = input("Please enter a valid choice: ")
                         else:
                              check3 = False
                    except ValueError:
                         move = input("Please enter a valid choice: ")
          myBoard, player1turn, lastRow = move2(myBoard,int(move) - 1,player1turn)
          printBoard(myBoard)
          won = checkWin(myBoard,int(move) - 1, lastRow)
          draw = isDraw(myBoard, won)
          if won == 1:
               print("Player 1 has won!")
          elif won == -1:
               print("Player 2 has won!")
          elif draw == True:
               print("It is a draw!")
          print()
          playAgain = input("Would you like to play again(y/n): ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description is short and to the point: It just keeps asking you for a move, but never makes it.

So, you are stuck in a loop where it asks this question. The loop starts here:

```
while won == 0 and draw == False:
```

and it ends behind the `except` block. The next line,

```
myBoard, player1turn, lastRow = move2(myBoard,int(move) - 1,player1turn)
```

is indented the same way as the `while` before, so it isn't part of the `while` loop.

I don't think you'll be surprised when I tell you that your code needs a lot of work, though. From comparing boolean variables to `True` and `False` (instead of just using them as is), to your very complex 'ask for a valid move' constructs, to lots of other things.

Streamlining your code will make it much easier to spot bugs, so I suggest to rethink most of your code. This is my idea, but I make no guarantee that it is any good.

```
while True:
    try:
        move=int(input("Please enter your move: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number")
        continue
    if 0 < move < len(myBoard[0]):
        break
    print("Please enter a number between 1 and {}".format(len(myBoard[0])-1))
```

(For python 2.x replace `input` with `raw_input`)

Answer (score 0):

Your `IndentationError` is raised on lines 35 in `main()`, and 7 in `printBoard`, where you have written `printBoard(myBoard)` and `elif item == 1:` respectively. The statements are unindented by one space, which throws the `IndentationError`. You also have an `=\`, which should not be there (it raises a `SyntaxError`):

---

```
#myBoard is a 2d array storing the board. col is the column a player is                                                                                                                                     
#trying to move, and player is the player to move. If it is a valid move,                                                                                                                                   
#the program will go ahead and change myBoard.                                                                                                                                                              
def move2(myBoard, col, player):
     if player == True:
         for i in range(len(myBoard) - 1,-1,-1):
             if myBoard[i][col] == 0:
                 myBoard[i][col] = 1
                 player = False
                 lastRow = i
                 break
     else:
         for i in range(len(myBoard) - 1,-1,-1):
            if myBoard[i][col] == 0:
                myBoard[i][col] = -1
                player = True
                lastRow = i
                break
     return myBoard, player, lastRow

#could't get this to work in time                                                                                                                                                                           
#                                                                                                                                                                                                           
#Saves the game to a text file                                                                                                                                                                              
#def save(filename, myBoard, player):                                                                                                                                                                       
#     fileThing = open(filename 'w')                                                                                                                                                                        
#     for i in range(0, len(myBoard)):                                                                                                                                                                      
#          for j in range(0, len(i)):                                                                                                                                                                       
#               fileThing.write(j)                                                                                                                                                                          
#          fileThing.write("\n")                                                                                                                                                                            
#     fileThing.write(turn)                                                                                                                                                                                 
#     fileThing.close()                                                                                                                                                                                     

#Returns 1 if player 1 has won, a -1 if player 2 has won, and 0 otherwise.                                                                                                                                  
#lastColPlayed is the last valid move that was made.                                                                                                                                                        
def checkWin(myBoard, lastColPlayed, lastRow):
    player1amount = 0
    player2amount = 0
    winDiagnol = 0
    winDiagnol2 = 0
    for i in range(len(myBoard)):
         if myBoard[i][lastColPlayed] == 1:
              player2amount = 0
              player1amount += 1
         if myBoard[i][lastColPlayed] == -1:
              playet1amount = 0
              player2amount += 1
    try:
         if myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == myBoard[lastRow - 1][lastColPlayed - 1] and myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == myBoard[lastRow - 2][lastColPlayed - 2] and myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == myBoard[lastRow - 3][lastColPlayed - 3]:
              if myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == 1:
                   winDiagnol = 1
              elif myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == -1:
                   winDiagnol = -1
    except IndexError:
         pass
    try:
         if myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == myBoard[lastRow + 1][lastColPlayed - 1] and myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == myBoard[lastRow + 2][lastColPlayed - 2] and myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == myBoard[lastRow + 3][lastColPlayed - 3]:
              if myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == 1:
                   winDiagnol2 = 1
              elif myBoard[lastRow][lastColPlayed] == -1:
                   winDiagnol2 = -1
    except IndexError:
         pass
    if player1amount > 3 or winDiagnol == 1 or winDiagnol2 == 1:
         return 1
    elif player2amount > 3 or winDiagnol == -1 or winDiagnol2 == -1:
         return -1
    else:
         return 0

#prints myBoard to the screen                                                                                                                                                                               
def printBoard(myBoard):
    for row in myBoard:
        for item in row:
            if item == 0:
                print("_", end="")
            elif item == -1:
                print("0", end="")
            elif item == 1:
                print("X", end="")
        print()

#returns true if it's a draw                                                                                                                                                                                
def isDraw(myBoard, won):
     Full = True
     for row in myBoard:
          for item in row:
               if item == 0:
                    Full = False
     if Full == True and won != 1 and won != -1:
          return True
     else:
          return False


def main():
     lastRow = 0
     won = 0
     draw = False
     player1turn = True
     print("Welcome to Connect Four!")
     playAgain = True
     while playAgain != "n":
          rows = input("Please enter a number of rows: ")
          check = True
          while check == True:
               try:
                    if int(rows) <= 4:
                         while int(rows) <= 4:
                              rows = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
                    else:
                         check = False
               except ValueError:
                    rows = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
          columns = input("Please enter a number of columns: ")
          check2 = True
          while check2 == True:
               try:
                    if int(columns) <= 4:
                         while int(columns) <= 4:
                              columns = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
                    else:
                         check2 = False
               except ValueError:
                    columns = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
          myBoard = []
          myBoardTemp = []
          for i in range(int(columns)):
               myBoardTemp.append(0)
          for i in range(int(rows)):
               myBoard.append([0] * int(columns))
          printBoard(myBoard)
          check3 = True
          while won == 0 and draw == False:
               move = input("Please enter a move: ")
               while check3 == True:
                    try:
                         if int(move) < 0 or int(move) > len(myBoard[0]):
                              while int(move) < 0 or int(move) > len(myBoard[0]):
                                   move = input("Please enter a valid choice: ")
                         else:
                              check3 = False
                    except ValueError:
                         move = input("Please enter a valid choice: ")
          myBoard, player1turn, lastRow = move2(myBoard,int(move) - 1,player1turn)
          printBoard(myBoard)
          won = checkWin(myBoard,int(move) - 1, lastRow)
          draw = isDraw(myBoard, won)
          if won == 1:
               print("Player 1 has won!")
          elif won == -1:
               print("Player 2 has won!")
          elif draw == True:
               print("It is a draw!")
          print()
          playAgain = input("Would you like to play again(y/n): ")
```